# Can we have two data in world map series ? one for scatter map and another for geo map

Tags: echarts

I have a problem for e-chart world map. Where I am trying to make the scatter and geo map in one world map.Geo map for plotting the areas and Scatter map for showing the colored region. i.e different country will have different color or same (depend on data). So is that possible..?

I have tried to set the option for geo and scatter but it shows two map.One of Geo and other of scatter.

Comment: This might help: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=map-parallel-prices

Comment: post the echarts options as an answer so that it will be helpful for others in future.